# Inserting multiple forms, which will be records to Mysql table by a single submit button

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on how to add a new form each time a user clicks on a button, then all these details will be inserted to the database when he clicks on "submit" button.
for example, 
A user wants to create an online quiz and each time he clicks on "add a new question", the new question form should be displayed. 
after the user finishes creating the quiz, he submits these details and then be inserted to the DB.

I'm working on how to add a new form each time I press for example this Icon (+)

and insert these forms at the end by a single button.

Means:

First: Press this Icon (+).

Second: a new form will appear and I can fill it.

Third: If I press again the (+) icon the same form will appear, keeping the previous one in the same page.

Fourth: after I added more than two form I'll have a single submit button that will add all the forms(records) into that table in the database.

My question is that how can I do that, what is the best option to do it and also if anyone can have a simple example I will really appreciate that.

I am using PHP/HTML .. PhpMyAdmin/Mysql

Thanks a million.

Answer (score 0):

You should use one form, and maybe fieldsets to encapsulate each section. 
 Having multiple similar items, you can use an array syntax in your input names, and even give them an index upfront.

For instance:

```
<form method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <input type="text" name="questions[1]" value="q1" />
        <textarea name="answers[1]">a2</textarea>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <input type="text" name="questions[2]" value="q2" />
        <textarea name="answers[2]">a2</textarea>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

When posting this to your php script, you'll have arrays of questions and answers in your $_POST.

```
<?php
print_r($_POST);
?>
```

Would look something like:

```
Array ( 
    [questions] => Array ( 
        [1] => q1 
        [2] => q2 ) 
    [answers] => Array ( 
        [1] => a2 
        [2] => a2 ) 
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I would say that I don't want the fieldset from the begining. I need to have one every time that I press the icon (+) ..  I'm really confused how to it and apprciate your suggestion again.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php   


/*I have created this simple form as an example, but this is only for adding
the  once a time and submit it every time. That's not what I hope to achieve!
The idea  is that I would like to have this form appears whenever I press (+)
icon without  submitting the form every time. I would rather have the
submission and so the  storage process into Database will be after I finish
adding many forms
*/


echo "<br/><a href='tryAddBy(+).php?gradePlanAdd' class='btn btn-info' >[+]</a>";


if(isset($_GET['gradePlanAdd']))
{
?>

<form action='moduleProcess.php' method='post' id='addquestion'    name='addquestion'>

<table>
<tr>

<td><label>Please type your question  :</label></td>

<td><input type = "text" name = "question" id="question" class = "form-control" value="Write your question .."/></td>

<tr>

<td><label>Mark :</label></td>

<td><input type = "number" name = "mark" id="mark" class = "form-control" value=""/></td>

</tr>

</tr>
<tr>
<td><label>Answers :</label></td>
<td><input type = "text" name ="Answers" id="Answers" class = "form-control" value=""/></td>
<td><input type = "checkbox" name ="isCorrect" id="isCorrect" class = "form-control" value=""/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label></label></td>
<td><input type = "text" name ="Answers" id="Answers" class = "form-control" value=""/></td>
<td><input type = "checkbox" name ="isCorrect" id="isCorrect" class = "form-control" value=""/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label></label></td>
<td><input type = "text" name ="Answers" id="Answers" class = "form-control" value=""/></td>
<td><input type = "checkbox" name ="isCorrect" id="isCorrect" class = "form-control" value=""/></td>
</tr>

</table>
<input type ="submit" class="btn btn-info" value = "Submit Quize" />
</form>

<?php

}
?>
```